# Pourrait-on employer « bonne séance » pour se référer à la fois à un film et à une dégustation de vin ?

Tags: expressions, usage, choix-de-mot

Je ne suis pas une usagère native du français, et j’ai des amis français qui m’invitent à la diffusion d’un film suivi d’une dégustation de vin dans leur nouvelle boutique de vin, évènements auxquels je ne peux pas assister.

Est-ce possible de dire « bonne séance » pour me référer à la fois au film et à la dégustation de vin au lieu de dire « bon film » et « bonne dégustation » séparément ?

Answer (score 7):

*Bonne séance* est tout à fait acceptable avant d'aller voir un film parce qu'il est courant de parler d'une "séance" pour la projection d'un film, mais pas tellement pour une dégustation de mets (on parlera moins couramment d'une "séance de dégustation"). On entendra plutôt alors *Bonne dégustation*.

Vous pouvez donc souhaiter simplement:

> Bon film et bonne dégustation

Answer (score -2):

Non, vous ne  pouvez pas dire « bonne séance » ! Cela n'est pas identifié comme étant une séance. « Bon film », tout seul ou autrement, dans le présent contexte des formules de vœux, n'est absolument jamais à dire non plus; pour « bonne dégustation » c'est différent, on peut le dire mais ce n'est pas très pertinent ; lorsque l'on dit « bonnes fêtes », ce que l'on a l'intention de communiquer c'est le souhait que tout se passe bien, que les évènements pendant les fêtes soient au mieux de ce qui est possible, que personne ne se trouvera malade à ce moment-là, par exemple ; on ne dira pas par exemple « bon repas de Noël ! » mais on dira « bon anniversaire ! » [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bon+repas+de+no%C3%ABl+%21%2Cbon+anniversaire+%21&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbon%20anniversaire%20%21%3B%2Cc0).
La raison apparente est que l'on ne met pas en doute que la nourriture soit satisfaisante ; c'est la même chose pour une dégustation et donc ces formules sont assez gauches, même si on reconnait une bonne intention de celui ou celle qui les utilise. On pourrait se demander pourquoi ne pas considérer ces évènements limités à la restauration et aux choses similaires sur le même pied? Pourquoi ne pas souhaiter que le repas se déroule bien, que la dégustation se passe sans mauvais incident ? Peut être que ce sont des évènements qui en eux-mêmes sont trop simples, trop restreint dans le temps pour que l'idée paraisse trop réaliste.

Si le film est un spectacle, ce qu'il y a de plus probable, les options suivantes sont acceptables ;

Référence aux  deux évènements

- Bien du plaisir à tous dans spectacle et dégustation !

Référence aux deux évènements comme à un seul

- Mes vœux à tous d'une soirée agréable !  (*évènements dans une soirée*)
- Mes vœux à tous d'un après-midi agréable !  (*évènements dans un après-midi*)

Comment: Pourquoi ne pourrait-on pas dire "bon film" ou "bonne séance" ? Ce sont des expressions tout à fait usuelles qu'utilise par exemple le personnel d'un cinéma au contrôle des tickets. Et même chose pour "bonne dégustation": regardez n'importe quelle émission type "top chef", et vous l'entendrez à foison.

Comment: LPH, comment croire que le français est ta langue maternelle comme tu l'affirmes alors qu'une fois de plus, ta réponse montre une ignorance crasse d'usages courants. Qui es-tu pour critiquer le "bon repas de Noël" que je souhaite à mes enfants quand il leur sera servi à la cantine ?

Comment: @Greg La mesure de la valeur de quelque chose ne peut pas être universellement le nombre des adhérents qu'elle a ; certains morceaux de musique moderne sont adulés par des multitudes et ce sont de bien piètres créations en comparaison à par exemple un *Judas Macchabeo* de Haendel, lequel morceau, bien qu'ancien, n'est connu que par peu de monde. Tel mot ou expression peut être entendu souvent mais ce sera selon un certain contexte ou dans la bouche de certaines personnes et finalement n'aura que l'étiquette « populaire ». (champ 1)

Comment: @Greg Les gens ne se posent pas de questions lorsqu'ils « décident » d'utiliser un nouveau terme ; ils s'en remettent, presque instinctivement et beaucoup, à l'ascendant de la personne de laquelle il émane et celle-ci généralement ne fait pas autorité en matière de langage, quels que soient ses mérites dans la société. On aurait accepté un Georges Brassens à l'Académie Française mais on y a refusé un Charles Trenet. Ne sentez vous pas tout d'abord l'ambiguïté inhérente à la locution « bon film » (c'est un bon film !) ? (champ 2)

Comment: @Greg Dans le contexte qui nous concerne la référence est déplacée ; on n'est nullement concernée par le film mais par l'effet qu'il aura sur vous ; lorsque l'on dit « bon anniversaire » on ne dit pas « bon 28 juillet 2019 » mais « Que ce que vous apportera  ce jour  ne soit que bonheur et heureuses circonstances ! ». Ce n'est pas de la langue fidèle à ses mots et, de plus, elle empiète avec une proximité irritante sur des concepts connexes, qui sur le plan d'une comparativement plus grande conscience humaine, (champ 3)

Comment: @Greg  sont actuels, pertinents. Ce que l'on dirait en anglais dans cette situation **est** de la langue fidèle à ses mots : « We hope you enjoy the film! », « We hope you enjoy it. ». Il faut trois mots de plus et les gens n'ont pas le temps de parler ; remarquez que l'anglais « enjoy it! » qui est une abréviation, va déjà dans le sens d'un langage perverti, tel que nous l'avons dans le présent cas en français. Serait-ce plutôt que les gens ne savent pas parler ou qu'ils sont las de paroles ? Je pense qu'il faut faire mieux, (champ 4)

Comment: @Greg  peut être laisser à des responsables versés dans l'art du langage la décision quant à quelles formes sont acceptables ; un savant est nécessaire en linguistique pour démêler la jungle inextricable des concepts mais le premier venu pourrait introduire dans le langage pratiquement n'importe quelle forme, qui devrait de plus être acceptée comme étant sacrée; ce n'est pas réaliste.  Je ne peux pas m'étendre beaucoup plus ;  j'espère ne pas avoir déçu votre curiosité en ce qui concerne seulement quelques uns des points que vous soulevez. (fin)

Comment: @LPH: ce ne sont pas des "responsables versés dans l'art du langage" qui décideront s'il est correct de souhaiter si "bon film" est acceptable ou pas: c'est l'usage qui à la longue impose telle ou telle forme, même si cela peut contrarier la logique ! Souhaitez "Bien du plaisir à tous dans spectacle " avant un film et on vous regardera avec des yeux ronds, et un petit sourire amusé par un usage incongru et trahissant que le français n'est pas votre langue maternelle. Sur ce, *bon vent* et (j'ose ? allez, oui, j'ose) *bonne bourre* !

Comment: Grammaticalement, syntaxiquement, et étymologiquement parlant y a-t-il des différences entre bon vent, bonne bourre,  bon film, bonne séance, bonne dégustation et bonne soirée, bonne journée, bon anniversaire  ?

Comment: @Dimitris Non, il s'agit à chaque fois d'une interjection ou exclamation marquant l'expression d'un souhait : "Je te souhaite un/une xxxx".

Comment: @jlliagre Merci ! J'ai réfléchi comme ça : Adjectif+substantif et n'ai pu trouver de différences. Donc, si l'on accepte bon anniversaire, pourquoi ne peut-on accepter bon film ou bien bon repas ?

Comment: @Greg Il me semble que le sens dans lequel « bourre » doive être compris est celui du sens figuré de « remplissage dans une œuvre littéraire », c'est à dire assertion sans valeur, sans rapport avec les faits ou la vérité. C'est une opinion qui du moins ne peut être que franche, sincère. En ce qui concerne l'amusement de ces personne qui ne sont jamais sorties de leur ghetto natal et que le moindre acte qui ne correspond pas au petit confort douillet de leurs habitudes grégaires effarouche, je ne vois pas de rapport (champ 1)

Comment: @Greg avec la valeur des locutions discutées ; de plus je ne souhaite ni refaire leur éducation ni les laisser prendre la mienne en main. En ce qui concerne une soit disant « trahison » et cette question de mimétisme animal que l'on perçoit infailliblement dans le contexte qu'elle évoque, je reste indifférent, c'est deux bonnes fois hors sujet. Quand la langue que je parle ne serait pas ma langue maternelle, qui sont-ils pour juger de la valeur expressive de ce que j'énonce dans cette langue, tous des critiques littéraires ? (fin)

Comment: @Dimitris La grammaire est sans complication, un simple rapport d'adjectif à nom modifié ; l'étymologie n'est pas vraiment une question importante; ce qui importe si l'on veut établir des différences c'est la sémantique.

Comment: @dimitris On peut, bien sûr. LPH pète les plombs. Ne tiens pas compte des affirmations sans fondement dont il émaille ses réponses.